# Query prevent form on submit response back from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to stop or disable the submit button if the user gets the message that email exist in database.

I have tried to put in a if between, but with no luck. No guru on jquery.

Some says that i should use e.preventDefault(); but where do i put it? Tried everywhere, but either the scripts don`t work or the user can register anyhow.

Maybe it's best to validate everything from the php?? Just thought jQuery was better when using validate plugin as well.

Any clue ? Thanks =)

Have this script:

Jquery:

```
    $("#email").keyup(function (e){
    clearTimeout(x_timer);
    var e_mail = $(this).val();
            if (e_mail.length > 4) {
        x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
            check_email_ajax(e_mail);
        }, 1000);
    }
}); 

    function check_email_ajax(e_mail){
        $("#email-result").html('<img src="../cms/assets/images/loading.gif" width="20px" height="20px" />');
        $.post('ajax/register.ajax.php', {'email':e_mail}, function(data) {
          $("#email-result").html(data);
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST["email"])) {

        if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    }

$email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

$statement = $link->prepare("SELECT email FROM FF_Users WHERE email=?");
$statement->bind_param('s', $email);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($email);
if($statement->fetch()){
    die('<i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="color:red;" aria-hidden="true"></i> <small>(taken)</small>');
}else{
    die('<i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;" aria-hidden="true"></i> <small>(Yeey :-) )</small>');
}}
```

Comment: Have you considered _enabling_ the submit button once the email is validated, and disabling it otherwise?

Comment: @XerenNarcy Yes, just like i wrote, been trying to hide the submit button as well (or show), but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was the best solution, but it works as it should do.

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

if email found:

```
echo '<script> $(document).ready(function() { $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled"); }); </script>';
```

if email not found:

```
echo '<script> $(document).ready(function() { $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled"); }); </script>';
```

It works :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can work whitout submit button perfectly, with a `button type="button"` . I think you are looking for something like this:

```
function check_email_ajax(e_mail){
        $("#email-result").html('<img src="../cms/assets/images/loading.gif" width="20px" height="20px" />');
        $.post('ajax/register.ajax.php', {'email':e_mail}, function(data) {
          $("#email-result").html(data);
          var result= $("i").attr("id")
          if (result==red){
             //If this is the result you stay on the page and user see the red message :)
          }
          if (result==green){
            //If result is green I imagine you want to go where the action in form tag says, so delete action from the form, you can simply redirect where you want:
            url = "your-file.php"
            $(location).attr("href", url)
          }
        });
    }
```

Add a id for icons:

```
if($statement->fetch()){
    die('<i class="fa fa-times-circle" id="red" style="color:red;" aria-hidden="true"></i> <small>(taken)</small>');
}else{
    die('<i class="fa fa-check" id ="green" style="color:green;" aria-hidden="true"></i> <small>(Yeey :-) )</small>');
}}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help =) I tried your script, but in console i get an error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: green (if the red flag comes out and user email exists). Also tried to change the die(); to echo(); instead, same.

Comment: Try with echo " "; instead of echo ();  It should be works because only returns a <i> with the id, and green is not a variable as you says in the error msge

Comment: Sorry for my delay of answer, been away for some days. But back to the script, if i try to use alert to show the result, it gets undefined no matter what, so it just won't get the id from php file?! Also tried with (this) and also echo without ().